# Type inference failed: RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo()

Tags: kotlin

From java:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(
    hasDescendant(withText(artistResult.getNameVariations().get(0)))));
```

Trying to convert to Kotlin:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(
    hasDescendant(withText(artistResult.nameVariations[0]))))
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
Error:(63, 71) Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter VH in fun <VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder!> scrollTo(itemViewMatcher: Matcher<View!>!): RecyclerViewActions.PositionableRecyclerViewAction!
Please specify it explicitly.
```

I'm not entirely sure where I can specify "it" explicitly. When this has come up previously it's because I didn't initialise the value correctly, but here I'm calling a method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I needed to add `<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` to `scrollTo`

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(
    RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
    hasDescendant(withText(artistResult.nameVariations[0]))))
```

Comment: but why do need to add this?

Answer (score 2):

One can get easily **confused** about **which VH** among many(specially if multiple VHs in a single RecyclerView) to **use**, you can simply use **Generic ViewHolder** i.e `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` like :

```
RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>

RecyclerViewActions.actionOnHolderItem<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>

RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

etc.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I´m just going to leave my solution here in case anyone needs it.

onView(withId(androidx.preference.R.id.recycler_view))
.perform(actionOnItem<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(hasDescendant(withText(R.string.settings_reset_app)), click()).atPosition(1));

Answer (score -1):

do this:
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(11))